# Pandas .isin comparison

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am using isin to compare two columns in two pandas dataframe in python. I am doing

```
df1['compare'] = df1['COURSE'].isin(df2['COURSE'])
df2['compare'] = df2['COURSE'].isin(df1['COURSE'])
```

Suppose I pulled two table data to pandas dataframe from a url such that, there is a regular text 'TEXT' in COURSE column in df1 and same text 'TEXT' but with hyperlink associated to it in df2. While doing the .isin comparison it returns False. I thought pandas stores data in dataframe as text if so does the text with hyperlink gets stored as something else? And is there a way around for this?

Comment: May be it's due to the character case mismatch. Would you mind adding some data to the question?

Comment: Yes I would do that but I am not sure how I share the text with hyperlink here.

Comment: Does the data come from an Excel file?

Comment: Choose one: [ENGL 2617](https://catalog.ysu.edu/search/?P=ENGL%202617) (Women in Literature), 2618 VS Choose one: ENGL 2617 (Women in Literature), 2618

Comment: Yeah, I get it. But where does the data come to the dataframe? Where do you load it from?

Comment: Hi Pavel, I am getting the data from a web page table.

Comment: I am using df1 = pd.read_html(html)

Comment: OK, can you please be more specific? Which page do you read? Which page do you read for df2 (most important)?

Comment: Or simply can you add to your post printouts of `df1.head()` and `df2.head()` which includes these supposedly matching records?

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. These are two links I am pulling:https://catalog.ysu.edu/archives/2019-2020/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-creative-arts-communication/department-communication/ba-journalism-sports-information-and-media-track/#curriculumsheettext  

https://catalog.ysu.edu/undergraduate/colleges-programs/college-business-administration/department-communication/ba-journalism-sports-information-and-media-track/#curriculumsheettext

Comment: There is a line in the page 'Mathematics Requirement (e.g., MATH 2623, STAT 2625)' one with hyperlink other without, which when compared gives false.

Comment: Have you compared the actual values in both dataframes? Are they certainly the same? Are dtypes the same?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. All I do is pull table from above links and use the above mentioned code to compare the COURSE column.